# LDA in Spark 1.3.1. Converting raw data into Term Document Matrix?

Tags: java, apache-spark, lda

I'm trying out LDA with Spark 1.3.1 in Java and got this error:

```
Error: application failed with exception
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "��"
```

My .txt file looks like this: 
 put weight find difficult pull ups push ups now 
 blindness diseases everything eyes work perfectly except ability take light use light form images 
 role model kid 
  Dear recall saddest memory childhood

This is the code:

```
import scala.Tuple2;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LDAModel;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LDA;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;

public class JavaLDA {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("LDA Example");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    // Load and parse the data
    String path = "/tutorial/input/askreddit20150801.txt";
    JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile(path);
    JavaRDD<Vector> parsedData = data.map(
        new Function<String, Vector>() {
          public Vector call(String s) {
            String[] sarray = s.trim().split(" ");
            double[] values = new double[sarray.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < sarray.length; i++)
              values[i] = Double.parseDouble(sarray[i]);
            return Vectors.dense(values);
          }
        }
    );
    // Index documents with unique IDs
    JavaPairRDD<Long, Vector> corpus = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(parsedData.zipWithIndex().map(
        new Function<Tuple2<Vector, Long>, Tuple2<Long, Vector>>() {
          public Tuple2<Long, Vector> call(Tuple2<Vector, Long> doc_id) {
            return doc_id.swap();
          }
        }
    ));
    corpus.cache();

    // Cluster the documents into three topics using LDA
    LDAModel ldaModel = new LDA().setK(100).run(corpus);

    // Output topics. Each is a distribution over words (matching word count vectors)
    System.out.println("Learned topics (as distributions over vocab of " + ldaModel.vocabSize()
        + " words):");
    Matrix topics = ldaModel.topicsMatrix();
    for (int topic = 0; topic < 100; topic++) {
      System.out.print("Topic " + topic + ":");
      for (int word = 0; word < ldaModel.vocabSize(); word++) {
        System.out.print(" " + topics.apply(word, topic));
      }
      System.out.println();
    }

    ldaModel.save(sc.sc(), "myLDAModel");

  }
}
```

Anyone know why this happened? I'm just trying LDA Spark for the first time. Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with LDA! You are trying to convert a string to number. check that!

Comment: I took the code from here. I only changed DistributedLDAModel to LDAModel http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html

Comment: What does that mean? Did you really read your error message? "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "��" "

Comment: I'm telling you that this is not the issue. The issue is with input you are trying to parse.

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant. I thought you said I was not supposed to convert words into frequencies.

Comment: Where did you read me saying that? It's ok but your question is misleading, please edit so other can know what is it really about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
values[i] = Double.parseDouble(sarray[i]);
```

Why are you trying to convert each word of your text file into a Double?

That's the answer to your issue:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I took the code from here. I only changed DistributedLDAModel to LDAModel http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html Why are they doing that?

Comment: Because their input is double indeed: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/data/mllib/kmeans_data.txt   But you are loading plain text

Comment: wrong link sorry: this one is for lda: https://apache.googlesource.com/spark/+/branch-1.3/data/mllib/sample_lda_data.txt?autodive=0%2F

Comment: I see. So they already converted the documents into TermDocumentMatrix. Is there a way to do that in Spark? I found this one, but I don't think it's the solution. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html

Comment: Yes, you have to convert documents into term count vectors. What you want is to use CountVectorizer: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/ml-features.html

Comment: The link you added is a solution as well. CountVectorizer is one of the options to build a corpus for the LDA model, but you can use TF/IDF as well or any other approach from your link

Comment: Got it! I'm thinking of updating Spark 1.3.1 to 1.5.1 since these seem to be in later versions. Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is expecting the input file to be a bunch of lines of whitespace separated text that looks like numbers. Assuming your text is words instead:

Get a list of every word that appears in your corpus:

```
JavaRDD<String> words =
        data.flatMap((FlatMapFunction<String, String>) s -> {
            s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");
            s = s.toLowerCase();
            return Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));
        });
```

Make a map giving each word an integer associated with it:

```
Map<String, Long> vocab = words.zipWithIndex().collectAsMap();
```

Then instead of your `parsedData` doing what it's doing up there, make it look up each word, find the associated number, go to that location in an array, and add 1 to the count for that word.

```
JavaRDD<Vector> tokens = data.map(
        (Function<String, Vector>) s -> {
            String[] vals = s.split("\\s");
            double[] idx = new double[vocab.size() + 1];
            for (String val : vals) {
                idx[vocab.get(val).intValue()] += 1.0;
            }
            return Vectors.dense(idx);
        }
    );
```

This results in an RDD of vectors, where each vector is vocab.size() long, and each spot in the vector is the count of how many times that vocab word appeared in the line.

I modified this code slightly from what I'm currently using and didn't test it, so there could be errors in it. Good luck!

Comment: This code doesn't work since you preprocessed the input text replacing all non-alphanumeric chars and applying lowercase but in your JavaRDD<Vector> building you only split by space, so it is impossible to find some tokens in **vocab** map. Your code throws a NullPointerException.

But avoiding that error, it is a good explanation and it helped me to solve my doubts about this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Another error: you need to apply a **distinct** operation to the **words** RDD before creation vocabulary because you may find repeated words and when **zipWithIndex** is applied the line "idx[vocab.get(val).intValue()] may returns a NullPointerException.